# Kotlin equivalent of Python's bytes BytesIO struct module

Tags: kotlin, bytebuffer, bytesio, bytestream

I am totally confused, what are the Kotlin equivalents of Pythons...

- bytes - UByteArray yes I know
- BytesIO - a byte steam for reading (and later writing) bytes
- struct module - for conversion between bytes and int, float, etc.

I am targeting Kotlin/JVM.

Comment: Languages shouldn't in general be expected to have "equivalents" of each others' features. Please instead clearly explain *concretely what the "equivalent" needs to do or represent* in Kotlin, and make sure it is clear *why these separate bullet points should represent the same fundamental question*.

Comment: As stated in the question Karl, I need to read some bytes from a byte stream, then convert them into int64, double and so on.

Comment: I don't think the question says anything like that. Please try to be more explicit.

Comment: If you're targeting the JVM or Android, then [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) might be a viable option for you. It stores bytes and can be read from and written to (though it's not resizable). It also provides methods like `getFloat`, `putFloat`, `getInt`, `putInt`, and so on. I don't know if there's a Kotlin-specific equivalent.

Comment: That's assuming you want to do everything in memory. If you need to perform actual I/O, then you can also use the standard Java APIs for this, such as `java.io`, `java.nio.channel`, `java.nio.file`, etc. (again, if you're targeting JVM/Android).